# Transistor allowing voltage from base to emitter without collector

Tags: voltage, transistors, motor, raspberry-pi, breadboard

I am new to electrical engineering and was trying to create a transistor switch for my motor. In doing this, I noticed a bug when I disconnected the 5 V power source.

The circuit looks like the one below. My GPIO 23 giving 3.3 V is connected to the base of a NPN transistor, through a 5 kΩ resistor. The emitter is connected to an LED which is connected to ground on the Raspberry Pi.

I don't understand why current is going from base to emitter. Using my multimeter, I found that voltage across the resistor is only 0.6 V, while voltage through the LED is 3 V. How is this even possible? I thought the base just told the transistor to allow current to flow from the collector to the emitter.

[image]

I assumed this to be the reason I was having my first problem with my motor. The second image is a diagram of the fully connected circuit, which powers the LED but not the motor for some reason. I don't understand why any of this doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Your battery appears to be backwards in the second circuit. Is that intentional?

Comment: thats just a diagram problem, I didn't know it was backwards in the diagram.

Comment: Well, it changes the meaning of the schematic you drew, so it could be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your circuit you will have a 2 - 3 volt drop across the LED, but the transistor's emitter voltage will only be about 2.6 volts (about 0.7 volts below the base voltage) so there will be very little voltage left for the motor  (and the motor will likely require much more current than the LED will safely pass.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fARCbq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: so if i put the led after the motor, then the motor will turn on and the led will still let me know if the circuit is on?

Comment: How does volt drop work?

Comment: You should put the LED with a current-limiting resistor in parallel with the motor, so the LED won't have to carry the motor current.

Answer (score 0):

The conduction of the base-emitter junction is independent of the emitter-collector junction.When the collector is floating a BJT behaves like a diode.
Perhaps the small-signal analysis of the BJT will explain it better.

[image]

A transistor behaves like this T configuration circuit.When the collector is floated current going into the collector and the model doesnt want but the point I want to show is that the base emitter-bjunction   can be replaced with a diode which will conduct current Vbe>0.

Comment: ohh so its unrelated to my other problem then. Thanks! Do you know why the voltage across the resistor was so low but back to normal after the transistor?

Comment: You have connected the collector to a voltage lower than the voltage of the emitter.Also the voltage of the base is bigger than the voltage of the collector.